# How to make WKWebView not scrollable without a URL loaded in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

When I launch my browser app, it displays the address bar and the `WKWebView`, but doesn't have a URL loaded.
 
Since there's no URL, the view shouldn't be scrollable, but it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do the following in viewdidload:

```
webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "about:blank")!))
```

**EDIT**

```
@interface ViewController () <WKNavigationDelegate>
```

...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    webView.navigationDelegate = self;
    webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:webView];

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.de"]]];
    });
}

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = (webView.URL != nil);
}
```

Comment: Hi Andre and thanks for the answer :) However, I can't use this solution as it will just load about:blank every time the view is loaded (even if I switch to the settings or bookmarks view) which will be problematic for my app. What I think could make a nice solution but don't know if it's possible is have a function that disables scrolling if no URL is loaded. Do you know how to do something like that? Thanks :)

Comment: I tried your new edit, and using `webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = (webView.URL != nil);` on viewDidLoad did the trick :) Thank you very much Andre! :)